# Deleting all occurances of '/' after its 2nd occurance in python

Tags: python

I have a URL string which is `https://example.com/about/hello/`

I want to split string as `'https://example.com', 'about' ,'hello'`

How to do this ??

Comment: Haven't you tried anything? Any line of code? A tip: start with [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. You could use `re.split()` to split on a regular expression, for instance.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'\b/\b', 'https://example.com/about/hello/')
['https://example.com', 'about', 'hello']
```

`re` is part of the standard library, documented here.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split
The regex itself uses `\b` which means a boundy between a "word" character and a "non-word" character. You can use regex101 to explore how it works. https://regex101.com/r/mY8fV8/1

Answer (score 4):

Use the `urlparse` to correctly parse a URL:

```
import urlparse

url = 'https://example.com/about/hello/'
parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
paths = [p for p in parts.path.split('/') if p]

print 'Scheme:', parts.scheme       # https
print 'Host:', parts.netloc         # example.com
print 'Path:', parts.path           # /about/hello/
print 'Paths:', paths               # ['about', 'hello']
```

At the end of the day, the information you want are in the `parts.scheme`, `parts.netloc` and `paths` variables.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this :

1. First split by '/'
2. Then join by '/' only before the 3rd occurance

Code:

```
text="https://example.com/about/hello/"
groups = text.split('/')
print( "/".join(groups[:3]),groups[3],groups[4])
```

Output:

```
https://example.com about hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired in [Hai Vu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459745/hai-vu) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37076947/841339). This solution is for Python 3

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'https://example.com/about/hello/'
parts = [p for p in urlparse(url).path.split('/') if p]
parts.insert(0, ''.join(url.split('/')[:3]))
```